# conditionally iterating unequal lists with map() in Python

Tags: python

I want to do this:

```
a = ['xxx', 'yyy']
b = 'yyy'

for each_item in a:
    if each_item == b:
        print(['zzz'])
>>>['zzz']
```

I can do it with list comprehension:

```
print(['zzz' for each_item in a if each_item in b])
>>>['zzz']
```

Q1. Please tell me how to write this using map() function? These lists are  unequal length and first list could be large

Q2. What are other options to write this in functional programming?

Comment: List comprehension is as functional as using `map` in my opinion, and more pythonic by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for `filter`:

```
a = ['xxx', 'yyy']
b = 'yyy'

interesting = list(filter(lambda x: x == b, a))
print(interesting)
```

Or use a *generator comprehension* for larger lists:

```
a = ['xxx', 'yyy']
list_ = (item 
    for item in a 
    if item == b)
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the list comp, which includes an `in` test and outputs `'zzz'`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I guess OP was asking for the general concept rather then printing out `zzz`. Additionally, now when iterating over `list_` you can still print it out (or do whatever else you have to do).

Answer (score 2):

Its rather a `filter` than a `map`, so you should do it like this when you want to avoid list comprehensions:

```
filter(lambda x: x==b, a)
```

With `map` you could write:

```
map(lambda x: print(x) if x==b else None, a)
```

... but in my opinition its a bad style and  a mix of a purely fuctional construct (`map`) with a side-effecting action (`print`)

**Note**: Both `filter` and `map` return an iterable object in Python 3 but not a list. When you want access to all results in the `filter` and `map`, cast them in a list, i.e. `list(filter(...))` and `list(map(...))`

Comment: did you try to run this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use filter() instead of map(), for filtering out values from iterable in your case it's list, something like this

```
def check_for_value(input):
   if input==b:
      return True

result=filter(check_for_value,a )
print result
```

[you can find more about filter here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)